# How to do Square - like site development with versioning?

Tags: web-development

Our designer loves squarespace, because he can just build the site in their authoring engine.

We like that Square makes the site properly responsive for mobile/tablet use.

We are happy our designer is happy... but normally we use raw css / html, kept in a version control system.

Square does not appear to support versioning.

Is there a tool chain that gives us the designer-friendliness of square, with the versioning (and poss self hosting) we want from an ops perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Right at the bottom of the [features page](http://www.squarespace.com/feature-index#developerplatform) you will find:

[image: Screenshot]

So you can use git to version and manage your code, for offline/local self-hosting you will have to contact the sales team.

***Disclaimer***: I have no connection with Square or any of their associated companies.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! We asked their support this question a number of times and did not find this feature area to be actually useful in real life. Let me look into it further.

Comment: @samsmith Mention to their support line that if there is not **full git integration** that lets you *"work with a team and roll back changes easily"* then ask how many of their customers reside or trade in countries with legislation regarding false representation - you will either find the support team quickly putting you in touch with someone who knows what they are talking about or that section disappearing from the website.

Comment: http://help.squarespace.com/guides/squarespace-developer-platform-faq may be a good starting point for more information. So is http://developers.squarespace.com/initial-setup